# LinkedIn oauth in asp.net mvc5 application stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, linkedin-api

This is probably going to be a terrible question, but I am not sure where to start with this problem. I have not touched any of the code that integrates linkedIn with my webapp, but it just started throwing the invalid redirect uri error. I am using [this stuff](http://blog.beabigrockstar.com/introducing-the-yahoo-linkedin-oauth-security-providers-for-owin/) to get linkedIn in my application. Here is my startup.auth.cs file (key masked obviously):

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options: new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0,0,30,0),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Access"),

        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        var linkedInOptions = new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "fooooooooo",
                ClientSecret = "barrrrrrrr",

                Provider = new LinkedInAuthenticationProvider
                    {

                        OnAuthenticated = context =>
                            {
                                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("LinkedInAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                                return Task.FromResult(0);
                            }
                    }
            };
        linkedInOptions.Scope.Add("r_fullprofile");
        app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(linkedInOptions);
    }
```

In my account controller this is what it hit before it get the error message:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { returnUrl }));
    }
```

Above, the variable 'returnUrl' is null, however below redirectUri is "/Account/ExternalLoginCallback"

```
private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
            : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
        {
        }

        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }
            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
    }
```

Is there anything you see that could be problematic? What fields should I be looking at for this error? When I search the error it just comes up with generic answers about creating an application on linkedin, which I already did.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem related to yours. As yourself stated in your own amswer, after the update in Linkedin you will have to "specify your absolute return urls...". The problem in my case was to find out what was the exact "return URL" for Linkedin.
In my tests trying different redirect URLs I payed attention to the error message displayed in the response from Linkedin, and I finally discovered that in the parameter "request_uri" of their HTTP response, they were adding the string "signin-linkedin" (as if they were expecting that in the request).
So **I finally solved the problem** by adding that string to my original URL. Like shown in the following image:

[image: OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs form in Linkedin apps]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was an update (damn you heartbleed) to the security measures they take. Need to follow the steps [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/register-your-oauth-2-redirect-urls).

Short version: specify your absolute return urls when you set up an linkedin application.